# Round off decimal value in Nearest 10 or Zero

Tags: c#, double, rounding

Following values i would like to convert to round off figure. likes:

`60.72 --> 60.70`

`170.76 --> 170.80`

Currently, I'm converted to round off value using below method:

```
 getFee.ServiceRequestFee.ToString("N")
```

I'm not sure which `Match.Round` method suitable to my requirement.

Edit:

```
protected string Getroundoffdecimalvalue(string servicerequestsfee_val)
    {
        servicerequestsfee_val = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(servicerequestsfee_val), 2).ToString();
        return servicerequestsfee_val;
    }
```

I used this function even after i return 60.72 only and my expectation should 60.70.

Comment: So, [Bankers’ Rounding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.7.2#midpoint-values-and-rounding-conventions)?

Comment: why not overload math.round to make it suitable for your requirement?

Comment: See the examples in the link I posted. If you need a string representation, you can use `"N2"` as format.

Comment: @CommonMan - you might be correct. I found the solution through `Math.Round(yourNumber, 1)`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Math.Round(yourNumber, 1)
```

The second parameter is number of decimal places to round to. In your case you want 1 decimal place as an end result.

**

> You need to overload`Math.round` that takes the decimals parameter of
>   your choice and convenience.

**

Comment: I updated my question. I already tried your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.round and if needed convert the same to string.

```
  Math.Round(var_name,2)
```